# ошибка Expected expression после написания elif помогите решить пожалуста

Tags: python

```
    vvid = bool(int(input("1 если сортировать , 2 если считать: ")))
    text=str(input("Enter text: "))
    if vvid  == 1:
        data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
    print(data); 

    elif (vvid == 2):
    for letter in text:
        data[letter] = data.get(letter, 0) + 1
    print(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

во-первых:

```
text=str(input("Enter text: "))
```

у вас `input` и так строку возвращает, зачем ее еще раз в строку преобразовывать

во-вторых:

```
if vvid  == 1:
    data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
print(data); 

elif (vvid == 2):
```

соблюдайте отступы - на них питоша только и держится

```
if vvid  == 1:
    data = sorted(list(set(text.split())))
    print(data); 

elif (vvid == 2):
```

P.S.

и то, что я написал ранее в предыдущем вашем вопросе:

```
vvid = bool(int(input("1 если сортировать , 2 если считать: ")))
if vvid  == 1:
```

эта фигня будет работать ВСЕГДА!!!

ну перепишите вы уже по человечески

```
vvid = input("1 если сортировать , 2 если считать: ")
if vvid == '1':
```

так еще защититесь от случаев когда пользователь не число вводит

Comment: cпасибо тебе, добр человек

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)